# Can one see Morocco from Portugal?

Tags: morocco, portugal, vantage-points

Is it possible to see Morocco from the very south of Portugal, say, Faro or Lagos?

If so, which would one see more easily, Tangier or Rabat?

Both Tangier and Rabat are nearly at sea-level. The distance from Faro to Tangier is approximately 230 Km. The distance from Faro to Rabat is approximately 350 Km.

This question is based on a bet that I made with a friend. We're quite unsure about the real answer.

Comment: You can definitely see from Spain to Morocco.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I can also see the other bank of a river from where I am now, but what on earth does that have to do with the question?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo It seems a fair comment.  Portugal and Spain are both on the Iberian peninsula.

Comment: I am Portuguese, live in Portugal, many times spend my holidays in Algarve and have never heard anyone even mention that possibility. I have never seen Morocco from Faro or Lagos.

Comment: There is a LOT of Spain between Portugal and Morocco.

Comment: Useful site: https://beyondhorizons.eu/lines-of-sight/ . No entry for Portugal and a minor one for Morocco

Comment: You can check it for every location by calculation according to this formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon#/media/File:HorizonDistance.png

Comment: @JimMacKenzie but Spain shares a (very short) border with Morocco, so of course one can see Morocco from Spain. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I was thinking of Iberian Spain, but of course you are right :)

Comment: @WGroleau If you stand on the east-most point of Portugal than the Atlantic would be between you and the most part of Marocco, not Spain.

Comment: I didn’t say it was a straight line.  How about, “there’s a heck of a lot of Spanish coastline between …”

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What you need in order to see from country A to country B is not just the *distance* between them but *elevation*. The higher, the better. If the two countries are separated by water, then assuming ideally clear weather, what matters is whether the line of sight between the point you're standing at and the point you're trying to see dips below the surface of the ocean between them. Therefore the *distance* between those two points must be no larger than the sum of their *horizon distances*, which are a function of their elevation.

So look for mountains, not beaches.

The place in Morocco whose horizon distance reaches farthest in the direction of Portugal might be [Jebel Kelti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jebel_Kelti) (1912 m) about halfway between Tetouan and Chefchaouen, with a horizon distance ([corrected for atmospheric refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon#Effect_of_atmospheric_refraction)) of 169 kilometers. I've sampled a number of hills closer to Tangier, but they are all lower and their lines of sight don't reach as far into the Atlantic.

The highest point in Algarve is [Fóia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3ia_(mountain)) at 902 m, with a horizon distance of 116 km. I'm not sure if there are any almost-as-high peaks further east in Algarve, but ultimately that doesn't matter because the distance from Jebel Kelti to *anywhere* in Portugal is 277 km, and the sum of the horizon distances is 285 km. There certainly isn't anywhere as high as 902 m within the few dozen square kilometers of Portuguese coastal marsh that fall inside the 285-km circle.

Thus even assuming perfectly clear air and a telescope, you **can't** see any part of Morocco from anywhere in Portugal. (Except possibly in the case of very unusual meteorological conditions over the Gulf of Cádiz, which might in theory enable a looming image of Kelti to appear above the horizon).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It really answered to my question.
But under that, I have got a sub-question, very related: How far can you see in a perfect weather and with a telescope?
I'm not interested in 1 kilometer precise, but what distance we are talking about, is it 10, 50, 100, 200, 500 km?
I know it depends on the elevation, but if the conditions are the best?

Comment: Does this answer take the significant [atmospheric refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_refraction#Terrestrial_refraction) into consideration? Or do you by "ideally clear weather" mean that the entire atmosphere has been removed?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: "Ideally clear weather" indeed assumes that the atomosphere is optically homogeneous. I couldn't on short notice find a calculator that takes refraction into account (which would depend on meteorological conditions).

Comment: @Jakey: If you're standing on the beach with water lapping on your toes, you can see about 5 km of ocean surface. From the summit of Aconcagua in the Andes (6961 m) the horizon is 300 km away. I found these numbers by googling for "horizon distance calculator", which led me to ringbell.co.uk/info/hdist.htm

Comment: Wikipedia [Horizon § Effect of atmospheric refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon#Effect_of_atmospheric_refraction) has a simple formula that tries to take refraction into account . Of course it depends on whether we ask for "usual" meteorological conditions or extremely favorable ones. Wikipedia also has an article [Looming and similar refraction phenomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looming_and_similar_refraction_phenomena), so I guess "looming" is a term used for the extremely favorable conditions.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Ah, cool. With that correction we're still out of luck -- the sum of the corrected horizon distances is 285 km, which just barely allows you to reach from the Moroccan peak to a handful of square kilometers of Portuguese coastal marsh, but nothing as high as the 902 m the calculation was based on.

Comment: The shortest line from any point in Portugal to any point in Morocco is about 202.5 kilometers.  But those are both sea level.  That distance assumes I got the coordinates correct, which is questionable getting them from Open Street Map.  Since I didn't know how to draw it in OSM on my iPad, an image of Google's version is at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndnw2.png

Comment: From Málaga in Spain you can see mountains that are at more than 200 km.: https://www.ac.uma.es/~felipe/africa/ (in Spanish). Definitely refraction must be taken into account.

Comment: @Miguel: Thanks for that link. It turns out that the peak I was talking about is exactly Jebel Kelti, which I am now able to name in my answer.

Comment: Answer edited so the main numbers given now include the refraction bonus.

Comment: What about if you could get up one of those masts?

Comment: @ChrisH: I don't know which masts you are talking about.

Comment: There's a picture of Fóia on the wikipedia pages you linked.  It's got a couple of communications stations on top with rather tall radio masts

Comment: @ChrisH: They don't look all that tall -- compared to the height of the doorway on of the building in the picture I'd say 30-40 m -- corresponding to an increase in horizon distance of less than 5 km.

Comment: Possibly. I was only on a small screen and had a quick look for numbers without success. I was thinking of the ones further away on the right which might be a little taller but not the hundreds of metres needed to make the difference

Comment: I don’t suppose being on the roof of [the tallest building in the town of Faro itself](https://goo.gl/maps/R8XAmWMcoUm) (16 floors, approx. 60m tall), about 2 or 3 kilometres from the water, would be any improvement on standing at the summit of Fóia? Perhaps, if the 540m tall [Al Noor](https://www.alnoortower.com) is ever actually built and it does end up being in Tangiers, that might make more of a difference.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Jebel Kelti (with a horizon distance of 169 km) is 75 km from Tangier. A 540-meter tower would have a horizon distance of about 90 km. That won't be an improvement. As for buildings in Faro, they would be outside the 285-km circle where Fóia's elevation is sufficient, so no dice there either.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a loophole to win the bet (and possibly lose a friend): If you're flying from Porto to Faro, you're in Portugal and you can see Morocco before landing in Faro. Rabat might be outside your visibility range, though.

If you stay on the ground, see @HenningMakholm's [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/111803/65940).

Comment: Was thinking exactly the same, but from the other side of view:
If you're flying from Festo Porto, while you're above somewhere between Fes and Tangier, you're supposed to see the Faro or sorrounding :)

Answer (score 3):

No, but there are points in Spain where you can see both Portugal and Morocco. For example, [you can see](https://www.heywhatsthat.com/?view=BW9DV73F) to the north of Faro and into Tangier from the top of [El Torreón peak](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torre%C3%B3n_(pico)):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate this yourself for any distance. There is a mental calculation formula we use in the French navy to calculate the distance of the horizon.

It’s an approximate solution, but it works fine.

D = 2.1 * (√h + √H)

- D = distance in Nautical Miles
- h = height of your eyes in meters
- H = height of the object you try to see in meters (e.g. mast of a ship, lighthouse, hill)

It takes into account the refraction of the atmosphere, without it you should use 1.93 instead of 2.1.

Comment: An actual calculation example for Morocco/Portugal would be nice (someone already gave you a downvote, probably because you were not answering the question itself).